# Dimension too large when trying to plot a function using TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to display a function in x-range from 0 to 1000. The following code works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\xmax{200}
  \def\ymax{1}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.7cm, domain=0:\xmax, >=latex, yscale=1, xscale=0.05]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray,xstep=10.0cm] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (\xmax,3.9);
    \draw[thick, ->] (-0.2,0) -- (\xmax.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[thick, smooth, color=blue]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However the domain is in `0..200`. I thought that by increasing `\xmax` and decreasing `xscale` I could keep the final picture under control but I always get the error as soon as I exceed `\def\xmax{200}`.

How to achieve this?

### Edit

As suggested, I have tried using:

```
\begin{scope}[samples=400, yshift=-2.7cm, domain=0:\xmax, >=latex, yscale=1, xscale=0.05] ...
```

And it worked up to 400. If I increase `samples` and `\xmax` over 400 it does not work anymore. Same error.

Comment: There is already a problem with `\def\xmax{200}`. The number of samples needs to be increased. The curve has over 60 extrema, but the default sample size is only 25. Use something like `samples=400`.

Comment: Works when I define `\def\xmax{400}` and `samples=400` in `scope`. But if I try to go beyond in both fields it gives me that error again.

Comment: For example `\def\xmax{600}` and `samples=400` does not work. Also `\def\xmax{600}` and `samples=600` does not work. And `\def\xmax{600}` and `samples=100` does not work :(

Comment: The angle `\x r` gets too large because the angle gets converted to degree, before it is passed to the sinus function. The sample size is a different problem. If the number of samples is too low, you get artifacts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, of if I get your issue, but PgfPlots is a generally a good solution for plots.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}
    [
      height=10cm,
      domain=0:1000,
      samples=201,
      grid=both,
      axis lines=center,
      clip=false,
    ]

    \addplot[color=blue!70]  {sin(x)} 
       node[pos=.83,anchor=west] {$f(x) = \sin(x)$};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```